# fastapi using bool in route paths

Tags: fastapi

Is it possible to use bool parameters in route paths?

```
@app.get("/allprojects")
@app.get("/allprojects/{reload}")
async def GetAllProjects(reload:typing.Optional[bool]=False):
```

work using `/allprojects?reload=true`, but not `/allprojects/reload=true` nor `/allprojects/reload` will work, they both return:

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["path","reload"],"msg":"value could not be parsed to a boolean","type":"type_error.bool"}]}
```

I know I can create a separate route with reload as a `str` but would be nice to use bool parameters.

Comment: Just a quick comment, but your second route is intended to work with `/allprojects/True`. I think you could allow `reload` to be either bool or str. Then handle the str instance.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @astrochun, that hinted the solution, the 2nd line was actually a str which is not allowed in the function, so using a `typing.Union[bool,str]` and handling the str incident solves it:

```
@app.get("/allprojects", response_class=HTMLResponse)
@app.get("/allprojects/{reload}", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def GetAllProjects(request:Request, reload:typing.Optional[typing.Union[bool, str]]=False):
    """ get all projects from cache, reload=True will reread projects taking 3minutes """
    if isinstance(reload, str):
        reload:bool = True
    allprojects = gitlab.allprojects(reload=reload)
```

so now `/allprojects/reload` and `/allprojects?reload=true` reread, while `/allprojects` reads from database in 15ms

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution!